# How to set the origin of the object to the center of the face of the bounding box of that object using python API?

Tags: python, origin, source-code

I want to know how to set the objects origin such that it is in the middle of on of the faces of the bounding box. The input for which face to use will be taken by the user in the form of +X,+Y,-X,-Z, etc.
I already have some code which sets the origin to the base of the bounding box.

```
if obj.type == 'MESH':
  ob=obj
                
  me = ob.data
  mw = ob.matrix_world
  local_verts = [Vector(v[:]) for v in ob.bound_box]
  o = sum(local_verts, Vector()) / 8
  o.z = min(v.z for v in local_verts)
  o = mw @ o
  bm = bmesh.new()
  bm.from_mesh(me)
  bmesh.ops.translate(bm, verts=bm.verts, vec=ob.location - o)
  bm.to_mesh(me)
  bm.free()
  me.update()
  ob.location = o
```

Excuse the indentation but this is the basic block which sets the origin to the base.

I want this for each face of the bbox.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

actually  the tip is around this line code:

```
 o.y = max(v.y for v in local_verts)
```

you need play around axis, min/max values and the correct operator :

```
import bpy, bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
objs = bpy.context.selected_objects
obj =  objs[0]



if obj.type == 'MESH':
  ob=obj
                
  me = ob.data
  mw = ob.matrix_world
  local_verts = [Vector(v[:]) for v in ob.bound_box]
  o = sum(local_verts, Vector()) / 8
  
  o.y = max(v.y for v in local_verts)  ## change y for x y or z axis   and min for max
  
  bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = mw @ o  
  bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
```

[image: min_max bounding_box]